# Почему не открывается детальный просмотр новости?

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Осваиваю Битрикс. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Создал новостной инфлоблок. Анонсы новостей выводятся как положено, но при попытке перейти на детальный просмотр новости выводится ошибка "404 Not Found". Объясните почему и как это решить.

Мой файл urlewrite.php содержит следующий код:

```
   <?php
$arUrlRewrite=array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^\\/?\\/mobileapp/jn\\/(.*)\\/.*#',
    'RULE' => 'componentName=$1',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/mobileapp/jn.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/rest/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/rest/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
);
```

Настройки инфоблока следующие  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `news` != `new`, вероятно.

Comment: Не помогает, пробовал.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если файл urlewrite.php у вас сгенерировался автоматически, то папка у вас вероятно /news/. А в настройках инфоблока вы указали /new/ (нет S)
2. Проверьте какое значение параметра SEF_FOLDER при вызове компонента, /new/ или /news/
3. В настройках компонента в макросе детальной страницы должно быть *#ELEMENT_CODE#/*

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело в некорректном регулярном выражении. Судя по скриншоту у Вас URL детального просмотра конкретной новости будет вида `/news/<id новости>/`.

Регулярное выражение `#^/news/#` условно можно перевести как `начинается на /news/`. Но ведь у Вас после `/news/` есть еще и `<id новости>`. Но Вы не описали этого в регулярном выражении. Соответственно нет и совпадения.

Идем на `https://regex101.com/` и проверяем - `#^/news/#` или `/^\/news\//` для строки `/news/500/` - видим, что `/news/` попадает, а вот `500` нет. Изменяем на `#^/news/\d+/#` ( если у Вас Id новости - число), либо на `#^/news/.+/#` для любого варианта.
Проверяем. Ву-а-ля - вся строка попадает под регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение в urlrewrite.php верное, но в настройках инфоблока указано не "news", а "new". Плюс хорошо было бы посмотреть на настройки компонента - там тоже могут быть некорректные настройки ЧПУ.